# java lang RuntimeException: Failure delivering result on Activity

Tags: android, runtimeexception

As you can see this is my code, I built several applications in which I used several permission methods without any problem. In this case, I only have just one activity but it gives me an error while it wants to return the request permission result.

**Code:**

```
public class ActivityStartUp extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = { "android.permission.CAMERA",
            "android.hardware.camera", "android.hardware.camera.autofocus",
            "android.hardware.camera.flash",
            "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
            "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
            "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" ,
            "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"};

    private static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 0xBAB0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup);

        if (Utilities.hasMarshmallowApi()) {
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_CODE);
        }else{
            //Open an activity
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_CODE: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    G.permissionGrantStatus = true;
                    Log.i("Log", "Permission Status:" + true);
                    if(Utilities.hasMarshmallowApi()){
                        // Do something
                    }
                    // Do task
                } else {
                    G.permissionGrantStatus = false;
                    Log.i("Log", "Permission Status:" + false);
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result 
ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=47792, result=-1, 
data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} 
to activity {com.bvapp.sh.uni.watermanagement/com.bvapp.sh.uni.watermanagement.ActivityStartUp}: 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

As you can see in error "grantResults" has 0 length. I tried to find a good solution but unfortunately I couldn't fine a right one. why it's happening and how should I solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is you'r problem (from: [OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback() - Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html))

> **Note**: It is possible that the permissions request interaction with the user is interrupted. In this case you will receive empty
>   permissions and results arrays which should be treated as a
>   cancellation.

Comment: Well I'm still checking it, surprisingly this problem solved when I removed whole the permissions from manifest. When I want to add a permission it gives me that error again!!!! @T. Schlechtweg

Comment: @Mohsen Hatami Check your call of `requestPermissions();` in [Requesting Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) it states that `requestPermissions()` takes 3 arguments instead of 2. Are you sure your request is not cancelled?

Comment: @MohsenHatami also just check the length of your array, `if(grantResults.length > 0)` if you dont want the error.

Comment: I read an article and I used your advise and mixed it with onPostResume() method. In fact, onPostResume() calls after onResume() and onResume() calls after onRequestPermissionsResult() in activity cycle. However I suppose I have to find the reason behind this.